# How to set a refresh rate in a Subscribed Calendar

Tags: ios, ical, calendar

using the ical on the iPhone / iPod Touch / iPad **how can I set the refresh rate?**

or does it pick the refresh rate that I had set up in the Mac iCal App?

If no refresh rate was given in the Mac iCal App, what is the default refresh rate? 30 minutes?

Comment: What sort of calendar is it? Google/Mobile Me? Just on iCal on your Mac and iPhone?

Comment: a plain `.ics` file provided from a URL

Comment: I'd never worry about refresh rate. I just set my to sync with google calendar and as soon as I set anything on either end it's apparently pushed everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2019/iOS 12.3.1, these settings are under `Passwords and Accounts` → `Fetch New Data` → `Fetch`. It looks like fetch settings are applied globally to all fetch accounts - you can't set different fetch options for individual calendars or mail accounts.

Answer (score 2):

In "Settings->Mail, Contacts, Calendars->Fetch New Data" you can setup what to do. Depending on the account you can Fetch or Push updates to your iPhone - or choose to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

When viewing Calendar, click on Calendars button in top left.
Down at bottom left corner you'll see the refresh circular arrow.  Click it and it will refresh all subscribed calendars.

Comment: Is this setting the rate? It seems more a workaround unless you explicitly explain that the rate cannot be set (and why)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any option to set refresh rate's of calendars on my iPhone.

I checked my Google Calendar subscription in iCal and it had refresh of 15 minutes as default value. This value might vary depending on the provider of the calendar.

But AFAIK, calendars on iPhone don't refresh unless synced from iTunes.